# Submitting fingerprints for Schengen visa: determine whether 5 years have passed?

Tags: schengen-visas

I've had several Schengen visas pre-COVID. On one occasion I have been fingerprinted during visa application, but I do not remember exactly which visa was this. Now I'm going to apply for a new Schengen visa, and one of the questions is whether my fingerprints have been taken in last five years.

So I have following questions.

Firstly, is there a way to determine when my fingerprints have been taken? Is there any special mark on the visa? I've looked at my past visas, but can see no obvious mark.

Secondly, what dates are taken into account for the five-year interval? Does it start on the day when my fingerprints were taken (am I supposed to remember it?), or on the start date of my visa, etc? What date should fall within the five-year time -- the date when I submit my new application, the date of the start of my trip, the day of the end of my trip, the end date of my visa (if I'm applying for a multiple-entry)?

Finally, what can be consequences if I erroneously declare that I have not submitted my fingerprints in last five years? I'm OK with my fingerprints being taken once more to be on the safe side, but will it count as lying on my visa application?

Comment: Since a visa will only be **issued** after the (when required) fingerprints have been taken, take the issue date of the visas. The VIS system will contain this information, which a consulate official can see (but which a service provider cannot). If in doubt, you can check yes and in then in the field of 'date, if known' write **unknown**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, post as an answer, not as a comment, if not answered soon this comment might just disappear.

Comment: @Willeke The previous comment is based on my background knowlage (at al. reading the application form) and the usage of a bit of common sense. Unfortunatly there are many on this site that would contradict such an answer (as a statement of fact, often without reasons or sources confirming, what is nothing more than, their **opinion**). Since my previous comment is actually only an opinion (with no source to confirm it), it shall remain only a comment.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://ch.tlscontact.com/gb/lon/page.php?pid=faq the timescale is *59 months*, not five years.

> If your finger scans were collected within the last 59 months, then you won’t have to give new fingerprints for your next visa application(s) and personal appearance is not necessary. However, you have to provide a copy of your visa sticker issued after 20.11.2015. If you are not sure or do not remember whether your fingerprints have been captured for a Schengen visa within the last 59 months, you have to appear in person.

By extension of the final point above, declaring that you haven’t submitted fingerprints in the last 59 months will have zero consequences - it will simply mean you’ll need to provide biometrics. The relevant date of collection as I interpret the above-quoted guidance is therefore the date you attended your visa application appointment.

Comment: The visa application only asks about a previous fingerprint (not about when). After a (swift) search in the visa code I found nothing about a renewal of fingerprints. I suspect that this rule is based on when the previous VIS record is deleted due to inactivity (couldn't find that out as well on the fly).

Comment: @MarkJohnson article 13 paragraph 3: Where fingerprints collected from the applicant as part of an earlier application were entered in the VIS for the first time less than 59 months before the date of the new application, they shall be copied to the subsequent application.

However, where there is reasonable doubt regarding the identity of the applicant, the consulate shall collect fingerprints within the period specified in the first subparagraph. ...

Comment: @MarkJohnson ... Furthermore, if at the time when the application is lodged, it cannot be immediately confirmed that the fingerprints were collected within the period specified in the first subparagraph, the applicant may request that they be collected.  Link: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202